# Display interactive table

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

Is it possible in jupyter to display tabular data in some interactive format?

So that for example following data

```
A,x,y
a,0,0
b,5,2
c,5,3
d,0,3
```

will be scrollable and sortable by A,x and y columns?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible.
First install [itables](https://pypi.org/project/itables/)

```
!pip install itables
```

In the next step import module and turn on interactive mode:

```
from itables import init_notebook_mode
init_notebook_mode(all_interactive=True)
```

Let's load your data to pandas dataframe:

```
data = {
    'A' : ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    'x' : [0, 5, 5, 0],
    'y' : ['0', '2', '3', '3'],
    }
   
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

[see the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAgg9.png)

Comment: Please, when suggesting to install packages from inside the notebook,  steer away from using an exclamation point, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for modern ways to use `pip` & `conda`. You should be suggesting `%pip install itables`. The exclamation point route doesn't help deal with installing to the correct environment backing the notebook while the magics do. No symbol is even  preferable to the `!` suggestion because of auto-magics being on by default usually, the `%` gets added behind-the-scenes.